# Changing UI elements in Chaquopy

Tags: python, android, chaquopy

I am currently trying to find out how to change the text of my textview in my MainActivity(the UI is written in Java) from a Python module. I know I have to pass my mainactivity somehow to my python module, but I still can't figure out how to do it properly.
I'm using the Chaquopy SDK for python interaction.

My main activity looks like this right now

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //set the layout
        final TextView simpleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.simpleTextView); //get the id for TextView
        Button changeText = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeText); //get the id for button
        changeText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                simpleTextView.setText("After Clicking"); //set the text after clicking button
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Now I would need a function in python to be able to manipulate the textview.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary, what you'll need to do is:

- Add your Python module to the source code in [the appropriate location](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#source-code).
- Load your Python module using `getModule`, and call the Python function using `callAttr` (see the [Java API documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/java.html)).

Specifically, you could either:

- Have the Python function return a string, then have the Java code pass it to `setText`. For example, `setText(mod.callAttr(...).toString())`, where `mod` is the return value of `getModule`.

Or:

- Pass the TextView object to the Python function using `callAttr`, then have the Python code call `setText`. For example, if your Python function is called `f`, then you would write `mod.callAttr("f", simpleTextView)`, and the function would receive the `TextView` as its argument.

Comment: Thanks first of all ! The last option you have shown looks suitable for me. What would I need to import in the python side? And how would the equivalent of setting a textview Text look like on python?

Comment: *What would I need to import in the python side?* – Nothing.

Comment: *And how would the equivalent of setting a textview Text look like on python?* – The same as it does in Java, because both languages have similar method call syntax. See [here](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/python.html#classes) for examples.

Comment: Even easier than I thought, appreciated!